# Add point in the database and the rest of the points in order depending on the point added

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem:

In a mysql table there are geographical points as follows:

[image]

I add a point after point 1 it will become point 2 but the former point 2 must become point 3 and so on ....

[image]

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `editare_coordonate` 
                            (`id_pdf`,`ord`,`x`,`y`) 
                    VALUE('$id_pdf','$ord','','')");

$i_ord = 1;
$select_ordonare = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
                                        FROM `editare_coordonate` 
                                        WHERE `id_pdf` = '$id_pdf' 
                                        ORDER BY `ord` ASC");
while($row_ordonare = mysqli_fetch_array($select_ordonare)){
         
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `editare_coordonate` 
                            SET `ord` = '$i_ord' 
                        WHERE `id_pdf` = '$id_pdf' 
                        AND `Id`  = '".$row_ordonare['Id']."'");
    //echo "UPDATE `editare_coordonate` SET `ord` = '$i_ord' WHERE `id_pdf` = '$id_pdf' AND `Id`  = '".$row_ordonare['Id']."'<br />";
     
    $i_ord++; 
}
```

I've been struggling with this for 2 days and I can't shake my head :(

Comment: Each **new** points should be 1 and all other ones gets +1?

Comment: `update table set ord = ord+1 where id_pdf = 97605 and ord >= 2` then insert your new point 2. Of course you had better do these 2 queries in a transaction so either both get committed or neither get committed

Comment: No, respect the position where I enter the point eg if I enter after point 2 then the new point will be point 3 and the old point 3 will be point 4 and so on

Comment: The purpose is to order the points?

Comment: yes with the dot in the position where I inserted it

Comment: Then don't do that and simply `ORDER BY ord DESC` or eventually don't use the `ord` field and use the `id` to order your table. You are over complicating yourself when you can order in the opposite way

Comment: @RiggsFolly right! I just realized that a point could be inserted between 2 others ones thanks to the screenshot

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you please correct my code as you say I didn't quite understand please

Comment: Where and how is `$ord` set

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I insert a point in js that point has an ord number and that I increment with 1 -> $ ord = $ ord + 1;

Answer (score 3):

```
#tell mysqli to throw exceptions on error
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

#start a transaction
$con->begin_transaction();

try {
    #update the existing ord values
    $sql = "UPDATE `editare_coordonate` SET ord = ord+1 
            WHERE id_pdf = ?
            AND ord >= ?";
    $upd = $con->prepare($sql);
    $upd->bind_param('ii', $id_pdf, $ord);
    $upd->execute();
    
    # Add new point
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `editare_coordonate` 
                     (`id_pdf`,`ord`,`x`,`y`) 
                VALUE(?,?,?,?)";
    $ins = $con->prepare($sql);
    $ins->bind_param('iiss', $id_pdf, $ord, '', '');
    # !!!!! Would assume that the x and y points should be added into this query !!!!!
    # so that line should probably be 
    #$ins->bind_param('iiii', $id_pdf, $ord, $x, $y);
    $ins->execute();

    #if you get here, both updates were succesful so
    # commit both changes together
    $con->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    #something went wrong rollback any updates that may have worked before the error
    $con->rollback();
}
```